# Format numbers as money, two decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I turn, say 1499, to 14.99? The raw numbers will always be listed as "1999", "2499", "9999" etc. with the 2 last numbers being decimals. Preferrably in jQuery.

The only code I've understood assumes that there are no decimals already, or wants to round them, similar to

```
var num = 10;
var result = num.toFixed(2);
```

The number 19999 = $199.99
The number 149 = $1.49
so two numbers from the back are decimals. Ideas? I've seen plugins that should work, but I'd prefer not having to use a plugin for this relatively small task.

Comment: Can you share more test cases? or separating last two digits by comma is the only test case you are looking for?

Comment: Take a look at http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: How about change the number to String an replace the last two digits with '.xx'?

Comment: OP do not want to turn 1499 to 1499.00, please read again the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a nice way to do this is to loop trough a string obtained from the number and just add a dot or whatever when it should be added.

```
function toCurrency(n) {
    var value = n.toString();
    var output = '$';
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
        if (i === value.length - 2) output += '.';
        output += value[i];
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(toCurrency(2499)); // $24.99
```

This function could also be added as a prototype of Number like this:

```
Number.prototype.toCurrency = function() {
    var value = this.toString();
    var output = '$';
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
        if (i === value.length - 2) output += '.';
        output += value[i];
    }
    return output;
}

var price = 12200;
price.toCurrency(); // "$122.00"
```

I would do it this way, but I must say that modifying primitives is not recommended

Comment: Thanks. Many perfect answers, but this one made a lot of sense and was well elaborated.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid division which I do not trust due to floating point issues, here is one that does not use it:

```js
function dec(num) {
  var str = String(num);
  if (str.length < 3) return "$0."+("0"+str).slice(-2);
  return "$"+str.substring(0,str.length-2)+"."+str.slice(-2);
}

document.write('<br/>'+dec(9))
document.write('<br/>'+dec(99))
document.write('<br/>'+dec(199))
document.write('<br/>'+dec(1999))
document.write('<br/>'+dec(19999))
```

Comment: This is great. I started to write my own function, you were faster. But let's say, `num.length < 3`

Comment: Updated to handle < 3

Comment: Deleted mine since your is better and shorter. Also I think this is the best answer since it covers for the floating point issues.

Comment: with 56.2k you should get used to it. there was a time, when somebody always downvoted all my answers. from me +1.

Comment: Thanks both. It is just the principle. I would like very much to know WHY someone found it necessary to downvote.

Answer (score 4):

The code you have works perfectly, once you divide by 100...

```
function convert(value) {
    return (value / 100).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(convert(1499));
console.log(convert(2499));
console.log(convert(9999));
```

**jsfiddle example**

https://jsfiddle.net/8z15pb5c/

Comment: What issues in particular?  Realistically I'd floor the value in the function, as passing in pennies to convert to pounds (for example) should ignore any decimal places anyway.  That's an expansion of what's been asked and the OP will have to consider that *if* they ever need to.  They may know for a fact that all values are integers.

Comment: I meant Something like 1999 becoming 19.989999999999 or something

Comment: In that case, no.  That won't happen in the case of converting pennies to pounds, or similar in other currencies.  The ecommerce platform I work on works in this exact way and I have never experienced that happening.  We know for a fact that all monetary values are stored as integers so It would take a much more complex calculation to start introducing that kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
function convert(num) {
    return '$' + (num / 100).toFixed(2);
}

var num1 = 2499;
var result1 = convert(num1); // $24.99

var num2 = 99;
var result2 = convert(num2); // $0.99
```

Demo

```js
function convert(num) {
    return '$' + (num / 100).toFixed(2);
}

var num1 = 2499;
var result1 = convert(num1);

var num2 = 190;
var result2 = convert(num2);

var num3 = 99;
var result3 = convert(num3);

document.write(result1 + '</br>');
document.write(result2 + '</br>');
document.write(result3 + '</br>');
```

Comment: this will return 1.9 on 190

Comment: I think 99 should return 0.99

Comment: Now your solution is identical to @Archer's

Comment: That is not up to me :)

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be divide your number by 100 before call toFixed.
Sample: 
result = (num/100).toFixed(2)

Answer (score 2):

```
function test(number){
    str = number.toString();
    var len = str.length;
    var x = '$' + str.substring(0, len-2) + "." + str.substring(len-2);    
    console.log(x);
}
```